# set JOptionPane.showMessageDialog show front

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have Joption but it show in back of browser

```
public class LoginInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(LoginInterceptor.class);

@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {

    Map<String, Object> session = invocation.getInvocationContext().getSession();

    if (session != null && session.get("idUser") != null) {
        LOG.warn("session not expired");
        LOG.info("");
        return invocation.invoke();
    } else {
        LOG.warn("session expired");

        //this`s my joption dialog
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Session Expired");
        return "login";
    }
}
}
```

can any one know how how to bring it to front. Thanks for help ...

Comment: Make sure you specify the parent of the JOptionPane (instead of using null). If that doesn't help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @camickr how can I add parent class to my JOptionPane ?. I wolud edit my question.

Comment: @amor change `...showMessageDialog(null,...` that line to `...showMessageDialog(frame,...` or whatever name your `JFrame` has

Comment: @Frakcool Now solved after I add Jframe inside my JOptionPane. Thanks For help.. hehe

Answer (score 0):

I add this, and now solved

```
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();            
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Session Expired");
```

Comment: You should not need to create a new frame. I assume you already have a visible JFrame so use the frame as the parent of the JOptionPane.

Comment: if I just use this " javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Session Expired"); "   this give me an error " frame cannot be resolved to a variable " .

Comment: Yes well somewhere in your code you must create a JFrame. We have  no idea how you do this so it is up to you to manage the reference to the variable. We don't know the context of how the method is invoked in your application.